# Laravel running migrations, but not updating Migrations table

Tags: php, laravel, migration

Got a tricky thing happening with migrations. I run `php artisan migrate:fresh` and it says all five of my migrations are completed successfully, but there are only the first four of them listed in the migrations table. The DB shows the fifth migration was indeed completed, so now when I try to run my sixth migration, the migration runner thinks I need my fifth applied, and starts there, but of course throws exceptions because all that stuff already exists.

Here's the console showing all my migrations completed successfully

[image: five successful migrations]

here's the result of the Migrations table

[image]

Comment: and in your `.env` file you've got the database name that you are looking at in your database?

Comment: @nakov it is for sure the correct DB.

Comment: Try running composer dump-autoload and drop migration and migrate again

Comment: @JesusErwinSuarez tried that, did not resolve

Comment: Did you tried to delete the entire tables and migrations and migrate again?

Comment: @JesusErwinSuarez I'm running `migrate:fresh` every time, thats what it does

Comment: migrate:fresh may have an issue for some reason, try doing it manually. delete all tables and run php artisan migrate and lets see if that do something new.

Comment: can you try with `php artian migrate:fresh --force`

Comment: Please share your last migration file content. I think there is something issue with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a hybrid migrations file that uses part SQL script, part Laravel `DB::` and `Schema::`. Turns out the SQL script was wrapped in a transaction, and I guess that was screwing up the migrations table for some reason... maybe I'll look into it more tomorrow and hopefully be able to provide a better explanation.